# Is there one word that means "does not imply" or "does not automatically mean"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests, american-english, synonyms

I'm looking for one word that would more succinctly mean "does not mean" or "does not imply" or "does not predetermine." There are plenty of synonyms for "imply" or "predetermine," but not one word alone that fits the void.

The sentence would be as follows: I don't believe you should do X, but **that does not automatically mean** that I think you should do Y.

Even a re-arrangement of the sentence would be fine if a single word does not exist to convey the meaning.

Comment: "i don't believe you should do X--not to say that you should do Y."  You need negation here of some form.

Comment: Possibly related: [“Modus moron” rule of inference](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175267/modus-moron-rule-of-inference)

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using a negated form of *imply*

> imply
>
> verb (used with object), im·plied,im·ply·ing.
>
> to indicate or suggest without being explicitly stated

So you might say something like:

*I suggest you do x, but that does not imply you should do y*

Answer (score 0):

In logic the word "imply" is used to mean necessarily leads to the consequent. A ⇒ B means if A is true then B is also true. The arrow in logic means "implies". However in general English "imply" doesn't carry this meaning of necessity. Example:

> "His expensive car and clothes imply he's wealthy." (No necessity, only suggestion)

Therefore I'd suggest a stronger word, "entail".

> entail
>   1. To have, impose, or require as a necessary accompaniment or consequence: 
> The investment entailed a high risk. The proposition
>   X is a rose entails the proposition X is a flower because all roses
>   are flowers.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/entail)

> "His expensive car and clothes entail he's wealthy." (false premise,
>   doesn't follow) 
> "Killing a person entails you've committed homicide." (Means by
>   necessity)

Though it is a rather formal word. Another way of saying it is:

> "A doesn't necessarily follow from B."

Also, I would use "necessarily" instead of "automatically". but that's just preference.

Oh, I almost forgot to answer the question. There are some words which mean the negative of another word. For example the negative of "To do" is "To not do", which can be covered by the word "refrain". Or "indulge" - "to not indulge" or "abstain". In this case I can't think of such word for your example, I would just negate it with "not", "it does not entail."